# Separation of a convex set and a vector by a hyperplane

Tags: vector-spaces, inner-products

How a hyperplane separates a convex set. Please give me mathematical and geometrical representation and also I want to know the consequences after separations?

Actually, I was reading a scholarly paper, there I found these lines:
$v \cdot (y − x) \le 0, \ \forall y \in C$ (a convex set subset of $\Bbb R^n$), which implies that $C$ is separated from $x+v$ by the hyperplane $H = \{ z \in \Bbb R^n : v \cdot (z − x) = 0 \}$ passing through $x$ and orthogonal to $v$.

I didn't get meaning of these lines. Please give the explanation of these lines with geometrically representations.

Comment: (1) Clarification needed. Something cannot separate one thing; it can separate two things from each other, though. (2) What have you tried?

Comment: It would improve your Question to cite the "scholarly paper" that you are quoting from.  Also, see [here about using mathematical expressions](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) in your posts with $\LaTeX$ markup.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Here's a picture of the situation in the "scholarly paper".
The convex set $C$ is in red, and the hyperplane $H$ is blue.  The vector $v$ is $(1,0)$, so $H$ is a vertical line passing through $x$.  The inequality 
$v \cdot (y - x) \le 0$ for $y \in C$ says that $C$ is to the left of this hyperplane (possibly with some points on the hyperplane).  $x+v$ is to the right of the hyperplane.

[image]